# Mozilla vs Chrome Div width issue. Counting vs not counting borders?

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, mozilla

Hey guys I am having a small issue with an assignment. I have to create this page and it looks great in Chrome but every div cell renders one pixel smaller in Firefox, I believe it has something to do with border width. Is there a work around or something I am doing wrong?

I am using a CSS reset, and I have declared my doc type.

Should I have just built this page using tables instead? Sorry no link to published code, also when I place the code in the code block it still displays the HTML.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8uifJLGRXapcHF1VzRNNGo1b2M/edit?pli=1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browsers will never render a layout with identical pixel perfection. A one pixel difference is not be an issue. [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) may or may not help you in this case, but the sooner you get over trying to make websites display *exactly* the same in different browsers, the happier you will be.

Answer (score 3):

Try using CSS outline that will also work. An outline is a line that is drawn around elements (outside the borders) to make the element "stand out".

However, the outline property is different from the border property.

The outline is not a part of an element's dimensions; the element's total width and height is not affected by the width of the outline.

ie.

```
.example {outline: 1px solid pink;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the box-sizing property in CSS to fix this problem. `box-sizing:border-box;` will render the border and padding inside the actual width and height of the element. For a better description check this http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/